# Prove a.s. convergence of random variables.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

I need to prove this:

Assume that you have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$, $X_t$ is a stochastic process which is jointly measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\times \mathcal{F}$. Assume that $E[\int_0^TX(t,\omega)^2dt]< \infty$. Assume that you have a sequence of random-processes $X_n(t,\omega)$. Such that these are also square integrable with respect to $\lambda \times P$, $\lambda$ is the lebesgue-measure. And $E[\int_0^T|X(t,\omega)-X_n(t,\omega)|^2dt]\rightarrow 0$.

I then need to prove that $P(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^T|X_n(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega)|^2dt=0)=1$.

Any hints on how to solve this?

**My attempt:**

My only idea is to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma: We have that for those $\omega$'s where we do not have convergence, then there exists a k, such that for all N, there is an $M \ge N$ such that $\int_0^T|X_M(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega)|^2dt \ge1/k$. These $\omega$s can be written:

$\cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\cap_{N \in \mathbb{N}}\cup_{M \ge N}\{\omega: \int_0^T|X_M(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega)|^2dt \ge 1/k\}$.

By subadditivity it then follows that it is enough to prove that :

$P(\cap_{N \in \mathbb{N}}\cup_{M \ge N}\{\omega: \int_0^T|X_M(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega)|^2dt \ge 1/k\})=0$, for fixed k. By the Borel-Cantelli Lemma I need to show that:

$\sum\limits_{M=1}^\infty P(\{\omega: \int_0^T|X_M(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega)|^2dt \ge 1/k\})<\infty$, for each fixed k.

My only idea to continue is to use chebychev-markov, which says that :

$ P(\{\omega: \int_0^T|X_M(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega)|^2dt \ge 1/k\}) \le E[\int_0^T|X_M(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega)|^2dt ]\cdot k$.

So the result follows if:

$\sum\limits_{M=1}^\infty E[\int_0^T|X_M(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega)|^2dt ]< \infty$

By I don't see if this holds, do you? If so how?

If not, can you please tell me another way to try and solve this?

Comment: here is a counterexample showing only that your criteria is too strong. Take $X_M(t)=X(t).(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}})$ then unless mistaken under your conditions $X_M\to X$ in $L^2(\lambda(0,T) \times \Omega) $ note that also the P_lim =0 but your last sum can be rewritten $\sum\limits_{M=1}^\infty E[\int_0^T|X_M(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega)|^2dt ]=\sum\limits_{M=1}^\infty E[\int_0^T|X(t,\omega)|^2/Mdt ]=E[\int_0^T|X(t,\omega)|^2.dt].\sum\limits_{M=1}^\infty \frac{1}{M}$   which is not convergent. Best regards

Comment: maybe you should have a look at the three series theorem, sorry to be unable to do more. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to prove is simply not true as a general fact. Take as an example the special case in which $X(t,\omega)=Y(\omega)$ for all $t$, where $Y$ is a square-integrable random variable, and likewise $X_n(t,\omega)=Y_n(\omega)$. In this case your hypothesis amounts to the condition that $E[|Y_n-Y|^2]\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. It is well-known that while convergence in $L^2$ impies convergence in probability (this is just Chebyshev's inequality), it does not in general imply a.s. convergence, which is what you seek.